# Optocoupler relay driver - Help needed

Tags: relay, bjt, opto-isolator

I built the following circuit that is found on some websites:

[image]

The relay is on without applying any voltage to the optocoupler. These are the details:

- The relay's coil resistance is 720 Ω.
- As soon as I power the circuit I get 11.45 V across the relay coil.
- At the base of the transistor, I measure about 0.75 V.
- The input is floating (not connected).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem bulding the circuit? Show a photo to verify it is built so that it matches the schematics.

Comment: What is the voltage across the 2k2 resistor? Make sure you don't have the  4N28 pins 5 and 6 connected together.

Comment: If Vbe is 0.75V, then it is on, so check that opto is connected properly, and is not damaged.

Comment: Please ask a specific question

Comment: I verified the pcb layout and it looks right. Voltage across the 2k2 resistor is initially around 3V with a steady decrease . After a minute it's 2.6V. Components are all new.

Comment: I will try to verify the optocoupler.

Comment: With 2.6V across the 2k2, you have about 1.2mA flowing, so that explains why your output transistor is on. Looks like you either have the opto connected incorrectly or it is fried.

Comment: Thanks all for the pointers. We'll update here once I resolve it.

Comment: Your input and output share a common ground so the sections of the circuit do not need to be opto-isolated. By the way, if that's not your drawing or design then you need to credit it. (This is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).)

Comment: Drawing is incorrect. The input and circuit grounds are separated.

Comment: Optocoupler is good.

Comment: Well if you're not going to use a correct schematic (which will cause a lot of confustion) then please [edit] your question to explain that the schematic is incorrect and that grounds are separate. Please also add in the credit as requested already.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certain now that the base of the phototransistor (pin 6) cannot be left floating, and that's causing the fluctuations seen on the voltage across the 2k2 resistor.

Comment: That's right. You need to pull the base of transistor up using a resistor, typically 4.7K. When LED turns on, the transistor starts conducting and output turns on

Answer (score 0):

Even though per your circuit, that you state is not accurate to reality, the base pin 6 is floating, and can provide negligent current to drive the base, it is still recommended to add 100k Ohm resistance from base to ground, even though many functioning circuits function with it floating. This will remove any uncertainty to the floating base pin. But more likely your chip is either misconnected allowing a current path to pin 6, or the optotransistor is shorted... Perhaps a quick multimeter reading in diode test of the junction would give you more certainty? If in doubt, switch the opto out for a simple 4 pin PC817, and you should have no trouble at all, since you are not using the base connection anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but possibly you used acid-core rather than electronic grade solder to build the circuit, resulting in excessive leakage current from collector to base (adjacent pins) of the optocoupler.

There's nothing at all wrong with the circuit as shown. Floating base is fine and that's how they are typically connected.